# Add Border Styling to VBox in TornadoFX

Tags: tornadofx

In a view for my TornadoFX app, I have a borderpane that has a VBox on the left and right sides of the view (nothing in the center). As of right now, each VBox has the same background color so they kinda blend together. I would like to show some sort of separation between the two VBoxes (i.e. either one VBox has a slightly darker tint, a border color, or both). Would anyone happen to know how to add border styling to a vbox? Or add a background color?

For clarification, I'm looking for a way to do this inside the body of my View class definition so I'm not using a CSS or FXML for styling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a type safe style sheet where you define a class for each vbox and assign those classes to the vbox. Here is a complete app with the stylesheet, app definition and main view:

```
class MyApp : App(MainView::class, MyStyles::class)

class MyStyles : Stylesheet() {
    companion object {
        val leftBox by cssclass()
        val rightBox by cssclass()
    }

    init {
        leftBox {
            backgroundColor += c("#cecece")
            borderColor += box(c("#a1a1a1"))
            minWidth = 200.px
        }

        rightBox {
            backgroundColor += c("#fefefe")
            borderColor += box(c("#222222"))
            minWidth = 200.px
        }
    }
}

class MainView : View("My View") {
    override val root = borderpane {
        setPrefSize(800.0, 600.0)

        left {
            vbox {
                addClass(MyStyles.leftBox)
            }
        }
        right {
            vbox {
                addClass(MyStyles.rightBox)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Illustration of the above code]

If you're allergic to stylesheets you could set these properties inline or use an inline stylesheet as well:

```
class MainView : View("My View") {
    override val root = borderpane {
        setPrefSize(800.0, 600.0)

        left {
            vbox {
                style {
                    backgroundColor += c("#cecece")
                    borderColor += box(c("#a1a1a1"))
                    minWidth = 200.px
                }
            }
        }
        right {
            vbox {
                style {
                    backgroundColor += c("#fefefe")
                    borderColor += box(c("#222222"))
                    minWidth = 200.px
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, you can configure the corresponding properties of the nodes instead of applying styles. I won't give an example of that as you really shouldn't do it :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I like that you showed how to implement the background inside a style sheet. Those always seem to help keep the view class files cleaner by reducing code. Next step for me would be to figure out how to implement this in such a way that a user could select a light/dark theme and the background colors would adjust appropriately.

Comment: You're welcome. I provided a comprehensive demo app with dynamic theme here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50520076/change-style-sheets-during-app-execution-tornadofx